# CMake use foreach and find_library to return full path of libraries

Tags: cmake

I used a `list` to store names of libraries, and I would like to use `foreach` and `find_library` to find full path of each library. But `find_library` just returned the path of the first library. I checked [this post](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-February/012966.html), but problem still exist. My CMake version is 3.4.3.

```
SET(VTKLIBS_DIR)

FOREACH(LIB ${VTKLIBS})
        SET(FOUND_LIB)
        FIND_LIBRARY(FOUND_LIB ${LIB})
        LIST(APPEND VTKLIBS_DIR ${FOUND_LIB})
        MESSAGE("Lib: ${LIB}")
        MESSAGE("Found Lib: ${FOUND_LIB}")
        UNSET(FOUND_LIB)
ENDFOREACH(LIB)
```

Comment: I found a solution to solve this problem, `UNSET(FOUND_LIB CACHE)` worked.

Comment: You'd better just use different variable names for each lib.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Command `find_library` sets **cached** variable, but simple form of command `unset` remove only **simple** variable's definition.

As noted by the link you provide, you need to store *special value* `FOUND_LIB-NOTFOUND` to the variable `FOUND_LIB` for force `find_library` to search another library while variable already contains path to the previous library:

```
FOREACH(LIB ${VTKLIBS})
        SET(FOUND_LIB "FOUND_LIB-NOTFOUND")
        FIND_LIBRARY(FOUND_LIB ${LIB})
        LIST(APPEND VTKLIBS_DIR ${FOUND_LIB})
        MESSAGE("Lib: ${LIB}")
        MESSAGE("Found Lib: ${FOUND_LIB}")
ENDFOREACH(LIB)
```

Actually, this is some kind of trick, as *cached* variable `FOUND_LIB` isn't changed by simple `set` command. But when `find_library` implementation attempts to read cached value of the variable, it actually read value of *simple* variable with the same name.

Because `find_library` treats only `*-NOTFOUND` cached values as "library not found", your trick with assigning empty value to the variable doesn't work.

The better approach, as noted by @arrowd, would be using different names for variable, used in different `find_library()` call:

```
FOREACH(LIB ${VTKLIBS})
        FIND_LIBRARY(FOUND_LIB_${LIB} ${LIB})
        LIST(APPEND VTKLIBS_DIR ${FOUND_LIB_${LIB}})
        MESSAGE("Lib: ${LIB}")
        MESSAGE("Found Lib: ${FOUND_LIB_${LIB}}")
ENDFOREACH(LIB)
```

Such a way results for every `find_library` call will be stored separately, and the same library will not be searched again at the next time cmake being invoked. Also, such approach allows user to modify (in cache) paths to concrete libraries without affecting other ones.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to use different names for each variable `FOUND_LIB_${LIB}` which allows the loop *and* makes the caching work