# CMAKE: repeated calls to function with different arguments give the same results

Tags: c++, cmake

I have some helper functions which help me locate shared and static libraries in the filesystem:

I have a helper function which performs the actual search, given a `name` and a `suffix`:

```
function(do_find_lib LIB_NAME SUFFIX OUT)

    set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${SUFFIX})

    find_library(FOUND ${LIB_NAME})

    if(NOT FOUND)
        message(SEND_ERROR "unable to find library ${LIB_NAME}")
    endif()

    message(STATUS "search: ${LIB_NAME}.${SUFFIX} result: ${FOUND}")

    set(${OUT} ${FOUND} PARENT_SCOPE)

endfunction()
```

The function `find_static_lib` sets the appropriate suffix, and calls `do_find_lib`:

```
function(find_static_lib LIB_NAME OUT)

    if (WIN32 OR MSVC)
        set(SUFFIX ".lib")
    elseif (UNIX)
        set(SUFFIX ".a")
    endif()      

    do_find_lib(${LIB_NAME} ${SUFFIX} FOUND)

    message(STATUS "static lib search: ${LIB_NAME} result: ${FOUND}")

    set(${OUT} ${FOUND} PARENT_SCOPE)

endfunction()
```

Similarly, the function `find_shared_lib` sets the appropriate suffix, and calls `do_find_lib`:

```
function(find_shared_lib LIB_NAME OUT)

    if (WIN32 OR MSVC)
        set(SUFFIX ".dll")
    elseif (UNIX)
        set(SUFFIX ".so")
    endif()      

    do_find_lib(${LIB_NAME} ${SUFFIX} FOUND)

    message(STATUS "shared lib search: ${LIB_NAME} result: ${FOUND}")

    set(${OUT} ${FOUND} PARENT_SCOPE)

endfunction()
```

As required, elsewhere in my cmake hierarchy I use these functions to find various libraries

**The first time I use it, it works:**

First I search for `tcmalloc` static library.

```
find_shared_library(tcmalloc_minimal TCMALLOC)
```

Here is the resulting output:

```
-- search: tcmalloc_minimal.a result: /usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.a
-- static lib search: tcmalloc_minimal result: /usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.a
```

**The second time I use it, it breaks:**

Next I search for `protobuf` shared library.

```
find_shared_library(protobuf PROTOBUF)
```

Here is the resulting output:

```
-- search: protobuf.so result: /usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.a
-- shared lib search: protobuf result: /usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.a
```

**Error:**

Wah? Searching for `protobuf` with suffix `.so` finds the previous search result, `/usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.a`

**Question:**

- Why is this happening?
- Is there a bug in my functions?
- What do I need to do to correctly search for the requisite library?

**Notes:**

I have completed deleted my build directory and rebuild the makefiles, so don't believe this is an issue with a cache.

Comment: I am unsure that your question is formulated better than [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757842/cmake-use-foreach-and-find-library-to-return-full-path-of-libraries/), asked 14 hours before. Why this similar question is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation on [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/find_library.html):

> A cache entry named by `<VAR>` is created to store the result of this command.
>   If the library is found the result is stored in the variable and the search will not be repeated unless the variable is cleared.

[This cmake mailing list answer](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2006-November/011789.html) shows you have to set the variable to `FOUND-NOTFOUND` in order to clear the cache.

```
set(FOUND FOUND-NOTFOUND)
```

However, it could be argued that this is an **anti-pattern**, as doing this **defeats the caching behaviour** of `find_library`

It would be be better to use a unique variable name for each unique search.

Here the variable is called `FOUND_${LIB_NAME}${SUFFIX}`:

```
function(do_find_lib LIB_NAME SUFFIX OUT)

    set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${SUFFIX})

    find_library(FOUND_${LIB_NAME}${SUFFIX} ${LIB_NAME})

    if(NOT FOUND_${LIB_NAME}${SUFFIX})
        message(SEND_ERROR "unable to find library ${LIB_NAME}")
    endif()

    set(${OUT} ${FOUND_${LIB_NAME}${SUFFIX}} PARENT_SCOPE)

endfunction()
```